# Why minimization getting worse for bigger bounds?

Tags: scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to minimize this function:

```
    betas = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
    weights = [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]

    def get_beta_p(betas, weights):
        return sum([x * y for x, y in zip(betas, weights)])
```

With

```
    initializer = weights 
    constraints = ({'type' : 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) -1},
               {"type" : "ineq", "fun" : lambda betas: minimize_beta(initializer, betas)}) # sum = 1,         fun = 0

    bounds = tuple((0, 0.4) for x in range(len(weights))) # x from 0 to 0.4
```

So I use it into function

```
    def minimize_beta(weights, args):
        betas = args
        return get_beta_p(betas, weights)

    zero_beta=optimize.minimize(minimize_beta,
                            initializer,
                            method = 'SLSQP',
                            args = betas,
                            bounds = bounds,
                            constraints = constraints)
```

**Problem** In my homing opinion accuracy does not depend on bounds range, which looks really strange and unnatoral.

For example, when I use bounds (-0.1, 0.5), output is:

> [array([1.]), array([0.23947614]), array([0.15513421]), array([0.30120484]), array([0.36498963]), array([0.6351255]), array([0.06166346]), array([0.12740605]), array([0.55059138]), array([0.46437143]), array([0.42777512])]
> message: Optimization terminated successfully
> success: True
> status: 0
> fun: -0.15440870412170832 #look here
> x: [-1.000e-01  2.000e-01  5.000e-01 -1.000e-01 -1.000e-01
> -1.000e-01  5.000e-01  5.000e-01 -1.000e-01 -1.000e-01
> -1.000e-01]
> nit: 5
> jac: [ 1.000e+00  2.395e-01  1.551e-01  3.012e-01  3.650e-01
> 6.351e-01  6.166e-02  1.274e-01  5.506e-01  4.644e-01
> 4.278e-01]
> nfev: 60
> njev: 5

for (0, 0.2)

```
`fun: 0.17697693990449903
   x: [ 2.224e-17  2.000e-01  2.000e-01  2.000e-01  0.000e+00
        2.898e-16  2.000e-01  2.000e-01  4.457e-16  0.000e+00
        0.000e+00]`
```

for (0, 0.4)

> ```
>  `fun: 0.106654645436427
> ```

```
   x: [ 2.361e-16  1.700e-16  2.000e-01  8.746e-16  2.980e-16
        0.000e+00  4.000e-01  4.000e-01  3.434e-16  6.155e-17
        0.000e+00]`
```

for (0.0, 0.5)

> `fun: 0.09453475545362894 x: [ 4.951e-16  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  2.505e-16  5.714e-16 0.000e+00  5.000e-01  5.000e-01  6.418e-16  4.344e-16 5.516e-17]`

for  (0.0, 0.9)

> `fun: 0.06823772147966463 x: [ 8.633e-16  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  5.373e-16  1.113e-15 4.327e-17  9.000e-01  1.000e-01  5.260e-16  1.818e-17 0.000e+00]for (-0.2, 0.2)`

Should it be so? Why is it so unpredictable?

P.S: I could plot all results if you ask

Comment: The goal of *minimizing* is to find the lowest possible objective function value that fulfills your constraints and bounds. Your objectives values become lower with larger bounds and therefore it gets *better*, not *worse*. That said, why are you solving a linear optimization problem with a solver for nonlinear optimization problems (SLSQP)? Use [`scipy.optimize.linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) instead. In addition, solving the LP graphically with pen and paper for two variables might enlighten you.

Comment: @joni, I agree with you when there are just positive values in bounds like (0; 0.2). But when we use, for example (-0.2; 0.2) bound, y gets 0.5 vs 0.1 for bounds (0; 0.4). Bounds are the same width, result is worse, isn't it?